# Mailbox not in the scope

Tags: elm

I am trying to create a frontend using elm with elm-router in order to manage the routing.

I have this main file :

```
-- Main.elm
import Router               exposing (Route, match, (:->))
import History              exposing (path)
import Routing as Routing   exposing (route)
import Signal               exposing ((<~))
import Html                 exposing (Html)
import Signal               exposing (Mailbox, mailbox, Signal)
import Task                 exposing (Task)
import Test as Test exposing (pathChangeMailbox)

main : Signal Html
main = route <~ path

port runTask : Signal (Task error())
port runTask = 
    pathChangeMailbox.signal
```

This module to handle a mailbox. I could use a mailbox by page but it's ugly so I tried make a module to handle all the common code.

```
module Test where

import Signal               exposing (Mailbox, mailbox, Signal)
import Task                 exposing (Task)

pathChangeMailbox : Mailbox (Task error ())
pathChangeMailbox = mailbox (Task.succeed())
```

I also have a module `Routing` to list the route and associate action to them.

And here is the module to handle the menu, and so the navigation.

```
module Menu where

import Html             exposing (a, text, Html, div)
import Html.Events      exposing (onClick)
import Task             exposing (Task)
import History          exposing (setPath)
import Test as Test exposing (pathChangeMailbox)

display : String -> Html
display _ =
  div []
    [
      a []
      [ onClick Test.pathChangeMailbox.address (setPath "/CV.elm") ]
      [ text "Mon CV" ]
    ]
```

When I try to run the program I got the following error :

```
Error in .\src\Menu.elm:

Error on line 14, column 22 to 47:
Could not find variable 'Test.pathChangeMailbox.address'.

Looks like the prefix 'Test.pathChangeMailbox' is not in scope. Is it spelled correctly?
Is it imported correctly?

You can read about how imports work at the following address:
```

Do you have anyidea, why even if I import the `Test` module it's keep saying that `Test.pathChangeMailbox` is not in scope ?

Edit : Add Routing.elm

```
module Routing where

import Html             exposing (Html, div, text, br)
import Signal           exposing (Mailbox, mailbox, Signal)
import Task             exposing (Task)
import Router           exposing (match, (:->), Route)

-- Import displays
import CV as CV         exposing (display)
import Home as Home     exposing (display)

route : Route Html
route = match
    [ 
      "/src/Main.elm"   :-> Home.display
    , "/CV.elm"         :-> CV.display
    ] display404

display404 : String -> Html
display404 url =  
  div []
    [
      text "Erreur 404"
    , br [] []
    , text ("url : " ++ url ++ " not found.")
    ]
```

Comment: I set up the files on my local machine, installed elm-router and elm-history, but I can't find a module called Routing anywhere. Is that a module of yours that you forgot to share?

Comment: It's a module of my. I forget to add it. See the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've found a bug here. You should <strike>[file an issue](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues).</strike>
EDIT: [good job](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/927) :) Summary of the link: The problem comes from mixing the `.` used for qualified module access and record access.

Here's a workaround for now, import the name unqualified and use it unqualified. Note I also removed an extra `[]`:

```diff
@@ -4,13 +4,13 @@ import Html             exposing (a, text, Html, div)
 import Html.Events      exposing (onClick)
 import Task             exposing (Task)
 import History          exposing (setPath)
 import Test as Test     exposing (pathChangeMailbox)

 display : String -> Html
 display _ =
   div []
     [
-      a []
-      [ onClick Test.pathChangeMailbox.address (setPath "/CV.elm") ]
+      a
+      [ onClick pathChangeMailbox.address (setPath "/CV.elm") ]
       [ text "Mon CV" ]
     ]
```

(Menu.elm)

Comment: I tried your solution but now it's say `Could not find variable 'pathChangeMailbox'.

Maybe you forgot to say which module it came from?
Close qualified names include:
   Test.pathChangeMailbox`

I will try to open an issue I think.

Comment: @MaximeMangel I'm sorry, I shared the wrong diff. I've just edited. Your imports don't need to be changed in Menu.elm. That diff was just from a left-over from my investigating the issue.